# kitchen faucet not working

Tags: kitchens, faucet

I was running water into the sink while using the garbage disposal, but the water stopped coming from the faucet.  I turned the disposal off, but the water won't come back on now.

Comment: Seems like you'd want to tell us something about your faucet and plumbing. (Imagine trying to help someone who has told you what you've told us--wouldn't be easy.) Please revise your question to provide adequate detail.

Comment: only that sink or all the sinks? hot and cold? any leaks under the sink?

Comment: Single handle faucet or two-handle faucet?

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. We'll need more information before we can help you. And, you should probably [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know how best to participate here.

Comment: Only the kitchen faucet.  It's the kind that you lift up to make the water run.  When I tried it again this morning, it made a noise like pressure had built up, but no water came out.

Comment: Try to unscrew the aerator, where the water comes out, and see if it's clogged up.

Comment: I'll try that.  So you don't think the fact that it happened while I was using the garbage disposal is related?  Just a coincidence?

Comment: Incidental to, but not the cause of your symptoms. Vibration from the disposal may have dislodged some internal scale or rust inside of your pipes, which then flowed up to the faucet spigot and clogged the screen or aerator, or maybe even in the valve mechanism itself. The root cause however is the presence of that scale or rust in your pipes.

Comment: I agree with @jack it sounds like a clogged aerator, this or a chunk of gunk in the faucet but that would be rare because there is both hot and cold water supply’s .+